# Android: Gradle 4.1 sync failed

Tags: android, maven, gradle

My project was ok, then I reopened it, got informed that I should upgrade Gradle plugin, sdk (now v.27) appcompat (v. 27 too) etc and then it don't sync anymore. The message I get is:

> Gradle sync failed: path must be canonical but got: 'C:/Users/..(etc some folders)../libs/additionnal.jar!

Tried to move this and two more (now problematic) libraries to a simple path like `c:\abc\` but nothing changed.

Already changed the repository url to `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` and things didn't get better.

Please some light on this? Searched a lot already and nothing. Thank you.

EDIT: below is my `build.gradle`. Curious is this: only error pointed on this file is related to the line related to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'` (claiming same versions on project).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.packagename.appname"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
}
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
  compile 'com.andreabaccega:android-form-edittext:1.2.1'
  compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:0.4.0'
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
  compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
  compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.0'
  compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: You may want to edit your question and post the `build.gradle` file that is giving you this message, pointing out the particular line that is causing a problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare many thanks on this. Sorry to take your time. Edited above. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need those last three lines. Those JARs should be loaded by `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`.

Comment: Removed them. Synced again but event log keep with the same `Gradle sync failed: path must be canonical...`. Thanks.

Comment: IMHO, unless you're writing an email client, there is no reason to have JavaMail. For example, if you are using that to send emails silently, and you have baked in the account information and server, now anyone can grab that data from your APK and send mail from your SMTP server. That being said, you might try [an artifact version of JavaMail](https://github.com/konradrenner/kore-javamail) rather than JARs in `libs/`. Beyond that, I cannot explain your Gradle sync error, sorry.

Comment: No, please, don't say you're sorry, you helped A LOT, as always. I will follow what you're suggesting and, yes, I don't want people to use my SMTP server. You are the one. God bless you. Have a big and great 2018. You deserve it. Thank you.

Comment: What is the full error message for this ` 'C:/Users/..(etc some folders)../libs/additionnal.jar!`? And how did the previous `build.gradle` look like?

Comment: @chenrui thanks for the help. The full error message I put on my question, it's just this: `Gradle sync failed: path must be canonical but got: 'C:/Users/..(etc some folders)../libs/additionnal.jar!`. Nothing more. The (etc some folders) I refered are my local path, and I even changed this to a much more simpler path, as explained on question, without positive results. Finally, my build.gradle was exactelly this way, only chopped three last refs. to the libraries, as CommonsWare advised. Very tricky situation. Thanks